# Can't center vertical in div use line-heigth in chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, less

I want to use prop `line-height` and `height` center vertically a text input in one div.

Below is the less code snippets:

```
div.header {
  background-color: #6283E6;
  height: 70px;
  line-height: 70px;
  min-width: 1220px;

  input.search-input {
    border: none;
    border-radius: 16px;
    background-color: #C9D4F6;
    background-image:url('../assets/search.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 14px, center;

    height: 30px;
    width: 353px;
    padding-left: 49px;
  }
}
```

But the actual effect in chrome is in below:

[image]

So why this happened.

Can you tell me?

Below is my Jsx code, Header has only one parent node and this node is the root node.

```
class Header extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className={style.header}>
        <input type="text" className={style['search-input']} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Hello, please provide your html too.

Answer (score 2):

I tested your code, and it seems fine to me:

```css
 div.header {background-color: #6283E6;
  height: 70px;
  line-height: 70px;
  min-width: 1220px;
}

input.search-input {
    border: none;
    border-radius: 16px;
    background-color: #C9D4F6;
    background-image:url('../assets/search.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 14px, center;

    height: 30px;
    width: 353px;
    padding-left: 49px;
  }
```

```html
  <div class="header">
  <input type="text" class="search-input">
  </div>
```

There must be something else wrong in code that you didn't show us.

Remember div and input have default margin and padding, so set margin and padding to 0 for both.

Alternatives:

- Instead of fixing the height, you can use padding on the top and bottom.
- You can use flex.

Comment: Please use Stack Snippets, rather than JSFiddle. Stack Snippets are basically the same as JSFiddle, but they're built into Stack Overflow, so they can be incorporated directly into your answer. (That will also stop you from getting error messages when you try to use JSFiddle links!) I already updated this answer for you with a Stack Snippet.